# How we can inctrease node js performance : Req/sec

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have developed a product using nodejs as backend. When I hit the API using benchmark i get this result :

[image: Bencgmark result]

That is 190 req/seconds (approx). I want it to be like 4000 or something per seconds. How can we configure our nodejs to achieve maximum performance.

I have tested it on local host ( Macbook Air 4GB Ram) and on linux server.

Comment: What does `/smartstub/teks/test` do?

Comment: @robertklep it is a kind of API which returns response body and headers.

Comment: That's not very helpful in determining if that function may be the bottleneck. Also, you should probably let `ab` run a bit longer by increasing the number of requests it should perform (`-n 10000` or something).

Comment: @robertklep I tried increasing it to 10,000 also and got 350 req/seconds.

Comment: Still, without a clue as to what actual code you're running no one will be able to make _specific_ suggestions on how to increase the number of requests.

Comment: I am fetching particulat API name from MongoDb , doing some checks and sending the saved response body with saved headers for first time and caching it, so for second hit it gives the cached result. @robertklep

Answer (score 1):

There are few precautions we have to take while developing node js application.
Few of them

1. Avoid synchronous code
2. Turn off socket pooling
3. Don't use Node.js for static assets
4. Render on the client-side
5. Use gzip
6. Go parallel
7. Go session-free
8. Use binary modules
9. Use standard V8 JavaScript instead of client-side libraries
   10.Keep your code small and light
   Regarding allocating more ram for node js execution you can take help from below links,
   http://prestonparry.com/articles/IncreaseNodeJSMemorySize/ and for optimization,
   https://www.nginx.com/blog/5-performance-tips-for-node-js-applications/ https://engineering.linkedin.com/nodejs/blazing-fast-nodejs-10-performance-tips-linkedin-mobile

Comment: These links do provide great information but they are theoretical. I need someone who gone through same problem and solved it. Something practical. +1 for providing all the info under one place.